# How to find out if there is Javascript code that is listening to keyboard events?

Tags: javascript, security, javascript-debugger

How can I find out **if** there is Javascript code listening/intercepting keyboard events and ideally find the *exact line/location* in the code (e.g. in ChromeDev Tools)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My Answer is for **Chrome Browser**

- If you need to View event listeners registered on objects then you
  can use [getEventListeners(object)](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference#geteventlistenersobject)
- If you need to monitor events    use [monitorEvents()](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference#monitoreventsobject-events)

You can read [more about these API](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/events)

You can also observe these events from the Dev tools

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know on others brows but at least in chrome console in elements tab on the right side you can open the *Event Listeners* tab and see them all, moreover clicking on it You will find where they have been set.[image]

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div>
    <input type = "text" onkeydown="funct(event)"/>
</div>
 
<script>
     
function funct(e) {
   console.log(e);
}

</script>
```

```js
function funct(e){
  console.log(e);
}
```

```html
<div>
   <input type = "text" onkeydown="funct(event)"/>
</div>
```

Now run the program and go to inspect element --> console.
when you will enter some text in input box you will get all the listing of events fired in console

Comment: This gives information about all the events fired in this element, not all listeners on page